# what is wrong in my java zkoss program

Tags: java, zk

```
updated

<?page title="example"?>
<window  id="music" apply="com.main">

<combobox id="combo" autodrop="true" onChanging="music.suggest()"/>

</window>
java
public class main extends GenericComposer{

 /**
  * 
  */

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 Combobox combo;
 public void suggest() {
  combo.getFellow("combo");

  combo.getItems().clear();

            combo.appendItem("Ace");
            combo.appendItem("Ajax");
            combo.appendItem("Apple");

            combo.appendItem("Best");
            combo.appendItem("Blog");

 }

 }
```

it says null pointer exception y???

Comment: Stacktrace?  What line is the NPE on?  Is there any more source code around this example?  It doesn't look like you've initialised combo

Comment: @karianna ZK has autowiring for controllers and macros, which is what I think lala is trying to use here.

Comment: @Piotr Blasiak Thanks!  I should've googled that first :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code, you can give it a try :)

ZUL

> ```
> <?page title="example"?>
> <window  id="music" apply="com.mainComposer">
> <combobox id="combo" autodrop="true"/>
> </window>
> ```

Java

```
public class mainComposer extends GenericForwardComposer{
  Combobox combo; //ZK Auto Wired , use combo directly
  public void onChanging$combo() { // ZK Autoforward (Awesome !!)
    suggest();
  }
  public void suggest() {    
    combo.getItems().clear();
    combo.appendItem("Ace");
    combo.appendItem("Ajax");
    combo.appendItem("Apple");
    combo.appendItem("Best");
    combo.appendItem("Blog");
  }

}
```

Comment: thankyou for the code and can u please tell me how can i implement the autosuggest feature in this combo box .i didnt find any example related to it in zkoss using java

Comment: i found ZK have a demo "Combobox Autocomplete" http://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/combobox/autocomplete  is this the one you want ?

Answer (score 0):

Composers should extend the GenericForwardComposer and not Window. Try that and the autowiring should work.

Comment: You will also need to change use= to apply= .

Comment: lala, first of all - why are you doing combo.getFellow("combo")? I suggest you read the zkoss documentation if you plan to use zkoss (and you should, it is great) - because you seem to have misunderstood alot of how it works :)